# Strings from files to tuples in list

Tags: python, tuples, sage, split

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
3 & 221/73 \\\  
4 & 963/73 \\\  
5 & 732/65 \\\  
6 & 1106/59 \\\  
7 & 647/29 \\\  
8 & 1747/49 \\\  
9 & 1923/49 \\\  
10 & 1601/41 \\\  
6 & 512 \\\
```

I want to load the pairs of numbers into a list or a dictionary.

This is the code I have so far:

```
L = []
data1 = data.replace (" \\\\", " ")
data2 = data1.replace(" & "," ")
i=0
a=''
b=''
while data2[i] != None:
    if(a==''):
        while( data2[i] != '' ):
            a=a+data2[i]
            i = i + 1
        while(data2[i] !=''):
            b=b+data2[i]
            i = i + 1
    L.append((int(a),int(b)))
    a=''
    b=''
    i=i+1
```

But this is the error I get:

```
"while( data2[i] != '' ):  string out of range"
```

Comment: I think you are from C background! no string in Python don't terminate with `None`. there is no None char. You run loop over chars of string in Python as `for c_var in string_var:` not inside loop use `c_var`

Comment: what should the output of your code be like ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan you are right about C background.

Comment: @anmol_uppal Once I get these pairs, I have to plot them.

Comment: edit your question and give an output example in your question so that we can think of a more efficient way of doing the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that is a bit less C-like and looks more like python. Without being sure what exactly the output is supposed to look like, a first guess lead me to this solution:

```
result = []

with open("test.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
            l = l.replace('\\', '')
            elements = l.split("&")
            elements = [x.strip() for x in elements]
            result.append((int(elements[0]), elements[1]))

print result
```

This is the output:

```
[(3, '221/73'), (4, '963/73'), (5, '732/65'), (6, '1106/59'), (7, '647/29'), (8, '1747/49'), (9, '1923/49'), (10, '1601/41'), (6, '512')]
```

Note that this is missing error handling, so if the file does not conform to your format, this will probably throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you but there is still an error in 
>result[int(elements[Integer(0)])] = elements[Integer(1)]
>IndexError: list index out of range

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it, like [@Vor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29730432/4669462) mentioned, your conditional statements were the issue. Text files don't end with `None` in Python so you can't do `data2[i] != ''` and `data2[i] != None:`.

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    L=[]
    for line in f:
        line=line.replace(" \\\\\\", "").strip() #Replace \\\ and strip newlines
        a,b=line.split(' & ')                    #Split the 2 numbers
        L.append((int(a),b))                     #Append as a tuple
```

This approach would output a list of tuples, which you asked for:

```
>>> L
[(3, '221/73'), (4, '963/73'), (5, '732/65'), (6, '1106/59'), (7, '647/29'), (8, '1747/49'), (9, '1923/49'), (10, '1601/41'), (6, '512')]
```

**Note:** In your 3rd last line, when you append to `L`, you use `int()` on the `b` variable. Since the string is in the form of `'221/73'`, its not a valid integer. You could split the string and `int()` each individual number, but then it would divide the numbers, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: There is an error:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack in
a,b=line.split(' & ')

Comment: @Lior When you use `split(' & ')` on a string like this: `"3 & 221/73"` there are two values which can be unpacked, `3` and `221/73`. Are you sure your text file is in the correct format?

Comment: @Lior: That error message would only come up if a data line (after backslash removal) didn't match the format `string1 & string2`.

Comment: @logic my text file is in rtf file. should i change it to some other?

Comment: @Lior I tried my code with an RTF file and I got your error. I made my solution using a TXT file, so yeah, if possible, use that. Otherwise, edit into your question that you're using an RTF file.

Comment: @Lior Yes! Save it as a plain ASCII text file. The RTF file has extra hidden data in there to control fonts, styles, etc. It's not impossible to handle RTF files in Python, but plain ASCII is _much_ easier to work with.

Comment: @Lior: Excellent! Since logic's answer helped you, you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. And maybe also up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to replace  `data2[i] != ''` and `data2[i] != None:` with something like  this `i < len(data2)`.

Also your code will fail on that line `L.append((int(a),int(b)))` because `221/73` is not a valid literal.